# Map a matrix into a logical matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Looking for an elegant way to map a matrix into a logical matrix.
For example, if `n[i,j] >= 10` it should mapped into 1, else 0.

```
 12 34 3 4 10
 11 1  3 4 6
 2  34 4 3 22
```

should be mapped in:

```
1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ifelse`:

```
x <- matrix(c(12, 34, 3, 4, 10, 11, 1,  3, 4, 6, 2,  34, 4, 3, 22), 3, 5, byrow=TRUE)
ifelse(x >= 10, 1, 0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    1
```

Comment: Also, `(x >= 10) + 0`

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is the matrix

```
(x>=10)*1
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]    1    1    0    0    1
 #[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
 #[3,]    0    1    0    0    1
```

Or

```
(x>=10)+0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as:

```
 mat <- your.mat >= 10
 mat[] <- as.numeric( mat ) # the `[]` on the LHS preserves the structure.
```

E.g.

```
> mat <-  matrix(sample(1:20,16),4) >5 
> mat[] <- as.numeric(mat)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    0    1
```